# How can I assert that a function passed to a class constuctor is passed by reference and not duplicated when using composition?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

In the code below I can easily assert that `zombie` is an instance of `Zombie`.

When `zombie` is created the function `bitmapRenderer` is sent to it and becomes the function `render()` inside `Zombie'.

I am assuming that as `bitmapRenderer` is a function, which is an object, it is passed by reference. I can create as many zombies as I like and not be creating any more `bitmapRenderer` functions, no memory is wasted, but how can I prove that with an assertion?

```
function bitmapRenderer(drawable) {
    console.log('I am bitmapRenderer function', drawable);
}

class Zombie {
    constructor(renderer) {
        this.renderer = renderer;
        this.x = 100;
        this.y = 100;
        this.name = 'zombie';
    }
    render() {
        this.renderer(this);
    }
}

const zombie = new Zombie(bitmapRenderer);
console.assert(zombie instanceof Zombie);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `console.log(zombie.renderer === bitmapRenderer);`

This proves that they are the same because objects, even when they have identical properties, will always be treated as unequal unless they are the same reference.

```
var obj1 = { "a": "A" };
var obj2 = { "a": "A" };
console.log(obj1 === obj2); // false

var obj3 = obj2;
console.log(obj2 === obj3); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to test it in the Zombie class.
What can be tested is the consumer of the `Zombie`.
You will probably have a separate module with a factory which will create zombies for you.

```js
import Zombie from 'models/zombie`;

function spawnZombie () {
  return new Zombie(bitmapRenderer);
}
```

When testing this module you should mock `Zombie` so you can track how it was instantiated.
Specifically, you will check that `renderer` argument is the reference to your `bitmapRenderer`.

---

**Addition.**

But if you don't want to change your code a lot and keep it like in your example, you can just check that `zombie.renderer === bitmapRenderer`.
This is just a public field in your class.